# How to treat gender column (ordinal or nominal)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, feature-engineering

If we treat gender as ordinal data, we end up creating a single column with '0' for male and '1' for female.

Now, gender is a nominal data, therefore, it makes sense to one hot encode them, but it will result in getting two columns namely 'male' and 'female', but they are correlated, as only one of them can be true at a time, either you are male or female, so we can remove one column, now we are left with only one column consisting of zeros and ones, where '0' means male and '1' means female.

We know that both genders should be treated equally that's why we went for ohe, but Isn't the end result in both cases same.

What is the proper way of handling such types of nominal columns having only two states like gender column, attendance column etc.